# Extra blank div layer showing up on my website and I can't figure out how to delete it.

Tags: javascript, c#, css, visual-studio, saas

I have posted a website online that has a McAfee secure certificate. The Website "ends" and a layer appears underneath it, the McAfee certificate moves with the "phantom" div.  I have attempted to move these extra layer but have not been able figure it out these are the clues I have:

- When I comment out the javascript, the entire phantom layer disappears (my website also has no alignment whatsoever so this is not a real solution) so I assume the issue is in the javascript.
- When I inspect the site, it is VERY difficult to even highlight the "phantom layer" the one time I found it I found that the main container and the form were responsive but the "document" was a larger container that contained this phantom div.

Any help would be appreciated. I don't think the site secure certificate is the issue but my co-founder does so I'm including that info as he has more experience.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] of your attempt so far.

Comment: hey @AppleCat45, without something more to go on than this somewhat vague description of a problem, we're stumbling in the dark. is there any way we can see what's going on? or get some possibly relevant code?

Comment: create a fiddle if you can with your html and javascript and provide the link.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'll work on that. I'm new here.